# How to delete triggers that own by other users in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an installable trigger that is supposed to created once. But I found out that some of my coworkers have rerun my code and recreated another 3 triggers that are exactly the same. I felt so silly that I didn't add any conditional statement for that...

Anyway, now I want to delete these extra triggers. But I cannot find the delete/edit button on the console UI of the GAS project. And I've also tried  `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`, but it lists the triggers of the project that are only owned by me.

How can I delete these extra triggers created by others (owned by other users)? Or can I restart my project from a clean start again?

Comment: I don't think that a script project owned by one account can delete the triggers owned by another account.  Your code to create the triggers could get the `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` and if it's not you, then don't create the trigger.

Comment: @AlanWells I will surely added this condition now. Thanks. But it's hard to understand why as the owner of the project one cannot remove triggers or even see who owns them...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Alan Wells [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507537/how-to-delete-triggers-that-own-by-other-users-in-google-apps-script/56508334#comment99602934_56507537): no, you [definitely cannot](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions). What you can do, though, is make your users run a remover function on their behalf with something like this (if your script is container-bound, add it to `onOpen()` trigger if you have one, or to any other function that you expect to be called by others):

```
function deleteAllTriggers() {

  var ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  
  ts.forEach(function(trigger){
    
    var handlerName = trigger.getHandlerFunction();

    if(handlerName === 'yourFunctionName') { //check if you are deleting target trigger;
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
      Utilities.sleep(1000); //wait (in this sample 1s) to avoid "too many times" error;
    }

  });

}
```

---

ES6-style:

```
const deleteAllTriggers = () => {
    const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    triggers.forEach((trigger) => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Options')
      .addItem('Set Trigger (Only once)', 'createEditTrigger')   
      .addItem('Delete Trigger', 'deleteTrigger')         
      .addToUi()
}
//
function createEditTrigger() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var triggerExists = false;
  triggers.forEach(function (trigger) {
  if( trigger.getHandlerFunction() == "installedonEdit")
    triggerExists = true;
  });
  if (triggerExists){
     Browser.msgBox("Trigger already Created. Do not create again")
  } else {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedonEdit")
     .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
     .onEdit()
     .create();
     Browser.msgBox("Trigger Created now. Do not create again")
  }
}
//
function deleteTrigger() {
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
 }
}
//
```

The delete trigger will work for the triggers set by each user. Each user has to run it.

The create trigger function does not allow duplicate triggers with the same function name to be created.