# How to programmatically delete triggers owned by other users?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, permissions

I'm having trouble understanding the collective user rights to trigger deletions.

I know that installable triggers can only be deleted by the user who created them, but the verbiage in the [Google Scripts page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) seems to infer that programmable triggers (written in the actual code) can be removed/deleted by other users.

If so, why is that when I run a script to delete all triggers *from another user's computer*, it won't delete the trigger that I programmed *from my computer*?

This other [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507537/how-to-delete-triggers-that-own-by-other-users-in-a-google-app-script) is close to addressing the issue but only seems to talk about installable triggers (if I'm not mistaken).

```
/**
 * Creates a time-driven trigger.
 */
function createFirstTrigger() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('message')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
}

function deletingAllTriggers() {
   // Deletes all triggers in the current project.
   var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
   for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
   }
}
```

I've also tried deleting the original code for the trigger from another person's computer, but the trigger continues to live on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users can not delete each other's triggers.

The user who is having the issue, can open up their [triggers page](https://script.google.com/home/triggers)

Review all their triggers, and delete any triggers that they want to stop.

That user can also go into the security section of their account and review permissions given to third party access.

https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup

If the admin of a GSuite account needs access to a users file, what the admin should do depends on whether the user is still employed in the organization or not.  If the user is no longer at the organization, then the admin must:

- Remove company data from any of the users company devices
- Change the users password - Record the new password - you'll need it
- Reset sign-in cookies
- Revoke all application specific passwords
- Login in to the former employee's account using the new password and remove all recovery phone and email addresses
- Transfer file ownership of files that are still needed by the organization to other user(s)
- Make a copy of all data in the users account - https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout
- Delete the users account - There's no point in paying for an account that no one is using

If you want to stop a trigger from working at some specific date/time, then you could hard code a date into the trigger code to delete itself.  If you don't want to hard code it, you could put the date into Properties Service - Script Properties, so that any of the file owners could manually change the date.

When the trigger runs, it doesn't matter whether the user still has access to the file or the code.  The trigger will run regardless of whether the file owner has access to the file or their account, so the trigger can delete itself.

If you haven't written the function code to delete the installed trigger that runs it, then you'll need to have access to the users account.  If that user is not available, then someone would need to log into their account.  I'm not advocating for people to give out their password so that someone else can log into their account, I'm just stating what would need to be done.

The admin of a GSuite account can reset a users password, and then log into the account with the new password.

If the account that needs the trigger deleted, is a free/consumer account, then there is no way to get access to that users account.

If the code that created the trigger was in an add-on, then the add-on code could be written to check that users trigger, and delete it.  That's assuming that the add-on was already authorized to create and delete triggers.  For an add-on inside of a GSuite account, the add-on owner could write the code and publish the add-on within the company without needing the code to be reviewed by Google.

If the file with the trigger had been put into a Shared Drive, then other users would have access to that file.  However, if you wanted to use an add-on, then add-ons can't currently be installed in files in a Shared Drive.

[Documentation for Google Shared Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_with_shared_drives)

Comment: Hmmm... That's a bummer. What's the best way to manage triggers for a team of people then? If, for example, a trigger needs to be killed at a certain time, but the trigger creator is on vacation/quits/gets laid off/etc., how would one go about deleting the triggers that were created?
Is the best solution to have a group account that schedules the triggers so that all people who have access to that account can kill the trigger?